# Morph a view into another

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a view in my app that is replaced by another view by swapping their visibilities (gone <-> visible).

Those views are similar by content but no one is contained in the other.

Curenntly one view disappears and the other appears. I have another option of animating the visible out and animating the other one in. But I was wondering, is there a way to morph the first view to the other? It seems possible that it can be done by animating the size and regarding the content - split the content animation to three parts: blurring, replace content, un-blurring. Is there something similar?

Also any other solutions to replacing the views would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `ViewSwitcher`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher

You can customize the in/out animation, it holds 2 views, where only 1 can ever be visible at a time